# MySql - Loop through dates in a month for each row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. One is **Jobs** (master) table & other is **Allocations** (transactions) table. For each Job, I need to print the number of allocations done on each day in a month.

I need to print the number of allocations in the following format.

[image: Link to image]

I tried this using while loop in a stored procedure. But it did not help.

```
BEGIN

SET @start_day = DATE('2018-11-01');
SET @end_day = DATE_ADD(@start_day, INTERVAL 30 DAY);

SELECT 
job_id into @job_id
FROM 
jobs
WHERE
job_post_date BETWEEN @start_day AND @end_day;

WHILE(@start_day < @end_day) DO
 SELECT COUNT(allocation_id) FROM allocations WHERE allocations_job_id = 
@job_id AND allocations_assigned_date = @start_day;
 SET @start_day = DATE_ADD(@start_day, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
END WHILE;

END
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: A little clarification: you need some kind of pivot report having variable column count - one column for a day, right?

Comment: Can you split your task into: a) `COUNT(*) - GROUP BY allocation_assigned date`, b) `PIVOT`-ing result?

Comment: @PeterKsenak There is no error in my code, but my approach was wrong. It dint yield the result in the format I needed.

Comment: @AlexYu Yes. I need a pivot report with one column for each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can create dynamic sql by looping for all the number of days for the month in question, that should solve your problem.
Dynamic sql should look like

```
select j.job_name,
       sum(case when a.allocations_assigned_date = '2019-01-01' 
                then 1 else 0 end) as "1-JAN-2019",
       sum(case when a.allocations_assigned_date = '2019-01-02' 
                then 1 else 0 end) as "2-JAN-2019",
       sum(case when a.allocations_assigned_date = '2019-01-31' 
                then 1 else 0 end) as "31-JAN-2019"
  from jobs j inner join allocations a 
    on j.job_id = a.allocations_job_id
 group by j.job_name
```

Comment: Your code yielded the result in the format I required. Thanks.